# How can I share requires and use in ClojureScript namespaces?

Tags: clojurescript

I have alot of files in a ClojureScript project and the namespaces are getting very long. Is there a way to share part of a namespace definition and incude or share it so that I can just do something like:

```
(ns x.y.z
     (:use ...
     (:require ...
     (:include-common ... <- where this may use a 
                             shared definition of some use and requires
 )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do this with `ns`.